# How to find determinants for four matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, determinants

```
A=[1 2;3 4];
B=[5 6;7 8];
C=[8 7;6 5];
D=[4 3;2 1];

E=[det(A(1) B(1);C(1) D(1)) det(A(2) B(2);C(2) D(2));det(A(3) B(3);C(3) D(3)) det(A(4) B(4);C(4) D(4))]
```

I want to get a matrix which equals `E`.

If `A B C D` are very large, this is cumbersome to write by hand. How can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, get large, but not more matrices are added to this list, the following should do:

```
A = rand(20);
B = rand(20);
C = rand(20);
D = rand(20);
E = zeros(size(A)); % initialise E as big as the others
for ii = 1:numel(A) % loop over linear indices
    E(ii) = det([A(ii) B(ii);C(ii) D(ii)]); % build determinant
end
```

Comment: I find a question. When E=size(A) I can not get the right answer. When E = zeros(size(A)) I can get the right answer. May you explain the reason?

Comment: @Y.zeng run both commands, and see what the output sizes are. As well as read the documentation on both functions. Reading this, and other recent questions of yours, make me think it would be best for you to take a step back and go through [the MathWork's own tutorial on MATLAB](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) as you seem to be lacking understanding of several, if not most, basic concepts of the language.